# Unable to get jQuery.parseJSON() value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jQuery in one of my current project and face some problem in incorporation.

Here is the functions which I am using as follows:

```
$.fn.getEcval = function(c){
    var objType = c.type;  // get the value of 'pul' through alert.

    var hdf = $('input[name="eq"]').val();
    var objHdf = jQuery.parseJSON(hdf);
    alert(objHdf.objType); // get "undefined" through alert
};

$.fn.get_phnum = function(){    
    var url = $.fn.getEcval({'type':'pul'});
};
```

In `$.fn.getEcval` I send the parameter to get the value. I put the JSON string in my HTML hidden field. I get the string in the variable "hdf" which I have declared in the function.
When I run it in the browser  the alert function return **undefined**. But instead of **objType** if I put **pul** (i.e `alert(objHdf.pul)`) I get the proper output.

Here is the JSON data as stated below:

```
{
  "flg": 1,
  "alrd": 1,
  "drplen": 2,
  "qrr": "7055eced15538bfb7c07f8a5b28fc5d07055eced15538bfb",
  "wfa": 0,
  "ctp": "1",
  "pul": "b7c07f8a5b28fc5"
}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: need to know your php script response. how you write your php or server script. You must return a string with proper json format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the array notation.

```
 alert(objHdf[objType]);
```